# Socket IO with REDIS. Server not getting channel message

Tags: php, node.js, docker, redis, socket.io

I lost almost 2 days of googling and search trying to figure out what is wrong with my set up.
All my services are running inside a Docker container, all properly connected (I have tested it)

I have a minimal Socket IO Server on Node.JS connected to Redis:

```
require('longjohn');
require('dotenv').load({silent: true});
process.env = process.env || {};

var PORT    = process.env.SOCKET_PORT || 4567;
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(PORT);
var redis   = require('socket.io-redis');

io.adapter(redis({
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || 'redis',
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379
}));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(`New connection!`);
}
```

When I MONITOR this code on Redis, I got:

```
1520713149.833184 [0 172.20.0.8:40858] "info"
1520713149.833631 [0 172.20.0.8:40860] "info"
1520713149.834154 [0 172.20.0.8:40862] "info"
1520713149.839510 [0 172.20.0.8:40860] "subscribe" "socket.io#/#"
1520713149.840678 [0 172.20.0.8:40862] "subscribe" "socket.io-sync#request#/#"
```

Then a php App that connects and Emit to Redis

```
<?php

require(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Predis\Client([
    'scheme' => 'tcp',
    'host'   => 'redis',
    'port'   => 6379,
]);

$client->connect();
$emitter = new SocketIO\Emitter($client);
$emitter->emit('event', 'payload str');
```

And on Redis:

```
"PUBLISH" "socket.io#emitter" "\x92\x83\xa4type\x02\xa4data\x92\xa5event\xabpayload str\xa3nsp\xa1/\x82\xa5rooms\x90\xa5flags\x90"
```

So it looks like all come to REDIS but the socket io server doesn't get the event for an Unknown reason.

I was thinking about the different channel `socket.io#emitter`, `socket.io#/#` and `socket.io-sync#request#/#` used by both. But with all the article I have read, none of them used or changed them.

So maybe it's a package version that doesn't match? But all this version below are used by my co-workers... (I asked them for this problem, still looking)

On PHP, I use composer with:

```
{
    "require": {
        "rase/socket.io-emitter": "^0.7.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

And on Socket IO Server, npm with:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "~1.2.0",
    "longjohn": "~0.2.9",
    "socket.io": "~1.3.7",
    "socket.io-redis": "^1.1",
  }
}
```

If someone has an idea, I'll appreciate a lot ;)

Edit:
My co-workers use Vagrant and I gave it a try to see if something was different and yes, there is a difference in the channel subscribed by the socket.io server. 
It's `psubscribe" "socket.io#*` instead of `socket.io#/#` but they didn't touch anything about it and the sources are the same on both (docker and vagrant) kind of crazy right ?..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to separate the question and the solution. The problem here comes to my misunderstanding and lack of experience of socket IO and Redis.

I was expected to have a new connection when a client Emit through Redis. 
In fact, that not the case, the new connection will only come from a client that connects to the socket of IO. 
I use the DEBUG=* to see everything happening on the server and indeed yes, socket IO get the information from REDIS. I was by mistake and lack of experience only focused on the channel name.

I hope it will help a new padawan on Socket IO and Redis :)